# SQLDF Left Join in R

Tags: r, left-join, sqldf

My goal is to take 'matr', sort it by column c1, and keep unique(c1) where c2 = 1. For example, from this code...

```
c1 = c("a",'a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c')
c2 = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
matr = as.data.frame(cbind(c1,c2))    
one = sqldf('select distinct(c1),c2 from matr where c2 = 1')    
vs = sqldf('select distinct(c1),c0,c2 from matr group by c1')
sqldf('select matr.*,one.* from matr 
  left outer join one 
  where one.c1 = matr.c1')
```

arrive at:

```
c1 c2
a  1
b  1
c  0
```

For some reason, i lose row c in the left join. I can only arrive at (through other joins)

```
c1 c2
a  1
b  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `on` rather than `where` in the last sql statement.  With `where` it is performing the join and then afterwards applies the `where` clause whereas with `on` it does the join relative to the `on` condition.

```
> sqldf('select matr.*, one.* from matr left outer join one on one.c1 = matr.c1')
  c1 c2   c1   c2
1  a  1    a    1
2  a  1    a    1
3  a  0    a    1
4  b  1    b    1
5  b  1    b    1
6  b  0    b    1
7  b  1    b    1
8  c  0 <NA> <NA>
9  c  0 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me solve a problem I was struggling with.